# Cannot open bitmap files

Tags: java, bmp

I have a problem with opening bitmap files(widthxheight) in windows. Files are generated by a Java program which reads .dat files by 4bytes and write them as .bmp files. The weird thing is, if the width of the file is multiple of 4, the file can be opened (i.e. 400x450). However, if its not, I cant open the file and it says drawing failed (i.e. 450x400).

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hard to know without knowing what the Java program generating them is actually doing. Try giving more details on the way this program creates the files. Maybe something is wrong in the way it writes the meta data.

Comment: what do you mean by "width of the file"? i though you are reading .dat files...  maybe post some sample data

Answer (score 0):

BMP lines are padded to 4 bytes. Please make sure on write also on read to take care of that, see on net, wikipedia about BMP format.